# Software Updater failing with Requires installation of untrusted package in new Ubuntu 16.04 install

Tags: package-management, software-installation

When I click on
[image]

First I see

[image]

fyi I am definitely online.

When I click OK however I get this:
[image]

When I click Install Now I get this:
[image]

When I click ok the window just closes.

If I click on settings I have to authenticate and then I see this:
[image]

How can I get Software Updater working ?

Comment: Please show `grep -P '^[ \t]*[^#[ \t]+' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Accept that you want to install from untrusted repositories, if prompted

This causes, because you have at least one untrusted repo (not certified repository).

All repositories need a valid certification key, maybe at least one of your repos in the list has no valid certification key

A repository of an outdated certification key is e.g. VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by unchecking all the other sources.

I don't know which one was really the culprit.  I started by unchecking all the xenial stuiff and the cd rom but that didn't work so in the end I unchecked everything except for Canonical
[image]

This is not an ideal answer.  More of a brute force / hack and I might want some of those sources back so this may not be ideal - but might still be useful for others experiencing this.  Given recent security hacks in the news I wanted to be sure I could get basic software updates just in case.